# Filter outgoing mail by X-PHP-Originating-Script for Qmail

Tags: email, filtering

I host about 30 websites for clients on a rented server. Customers are often slow to update their Joomla and Wordpress installations. Sites get attacked quite often and I keep getting put on spam blacklists.

I would like to set up a whitelist of scripts allowed to send mail, and block all mail not coming from those scripts.
The server only has 30 or so sites on it, so I can set up and manage the whitelist manually.

Has anyone heard of an existing system to do this? Any reason not to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, would be to create a wrapper script around /usr/sbin/sendmail to do that for you. 
You can pass the script name to that wrapper and depending or not if it is on an approved list it can than proceed to send the email.

Quite some time ago I wrote on my personal blog what you are looking for and you can check it out [here](http://thanosk.net/content/monitoring-use-php-mail-function)

PS. For mods: If it is considered bad form to post a link on your personal blog I can remote it might try to recreate it here as an answer.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer? The link seems to be dead.

Comment: Some wrapper implementations can be found at https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam and https://www.iezzi.ch/simple-php-mail-wrapper/